# Which android view to use to display book like structure

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

Given I have a large text that I want to display on screen, which is paginated; which android view should I use? Viewpager seemed like a good choice, but I don't know if viewpager scales well if you have something like 10000+ pages on low end devices.

Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a book-like experience, with some libraries like https://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

Answer (score 0):

Viewpager by default only loads 3 pages at a time. Therefore it can be a good choice. However, you will need to create your own adapter for the viewPager.

I am guessing that the pages are stored in the file system. In that case it would be wise to create an object that can load the pages to the memory and pass it as argument to the adapter.